# Laravel Framework - How do i search a specific string in a array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, frameworks

My problem is that I have a huge array. In this array are the Browser, the user used to get on my website, but also bots and spiders.

It looks like this: Mozilla, Mozilla, Mozillabot, Mozilla, Unicornbot and so on.

I need to get every key in my array, that have 'bot' in it like mozillabot, unicornbot.
But I cant find something.

`array_search` doesn't work, `array_keys` too.

Does anyone know a solution in Laravel?

Comment: Can you update your question to include a small sample of your array and the expected result? Ex. you want as a result an array with all the bots or something similar.

Comment: Look at the [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Crawler Detect](https://github.com/JayBizzle/Crawler-Detect) library which makes it really easy to identify bots/crawlers/spiders. It can be as simple as a couple of lines of code. Below is a snippet taken from the library's documentation:

```
use Jaybizzle\CrawlerDetect\CrawlerDetect;

$CrawlerDetect = new CrawlerDetect;

// Check the user agent of the current 'visitor'
if($CrawlerDetect->isCrawler()) {
    // true if crawler user agent detected
}

// Pass a user agent as a string
if($CrawlerDetect->isCrawler('Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Sosospider/2.0; +http://help.soso.com/webspider.htm)')) {
    // true if crawler user agent detected
}
```

Comment: You can wrap the `isCrawler()` check in the callback of `array_where`. Nice! +1

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (str_contains($value, ['bot', 'BOT', 'Bot'])) {
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }
}
```

This will cycle through the array and use the laravel str_contains function to determine wether or not the array value has the word 'bot' or variants in it and then add it to a new array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel `helper functions`

```
$array = ['Mozilla', 'Mozilla', 'Mozillabot', 'Mozilla', 'Unicornbot'];    
$array = array_where($array, function($key, $value)
    {
        return str_contains($value, 'bot');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `array_where` helper.

Along with the `str_contains` string helper like so

```
$array = ["Mozilla", "Mozilla", "Mozillabot", "Mozilla", "Unicornbot"];

$bots = array_where($array, function ($key, $value) {
    return str_contains(strtolower($value),array('bot'));
});
```

Or with the `str_is` string helper, which uses pattern matching, like this

```
$bots = array_where($array, function ($key, $value) {
    return str_is('*bot*',strtolower($value));
});
```

The check is done against lowercase strings to avoid variations on "Bot", "BOT" and so on.